# Stored procedure insert two rows?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure using T-SQL.

I run it using this query

```
EXEC insertfbusers email, name
```

But when testing it in SQL Server Management Studio it inserts the same row twice, which causes a Primary Key violation.

The Primary Key is on the email column.

Why does it insert two rows?

Here's my procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- ================================
-- Created 
--    by: dbo
--    on: Monday, October 08, 2012 1:10 AM
-- Description: <Description>
-- ================================
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.insertfbusers
 -- Add the parameters for the procedure here
 @email varchar(100),
 @firstname varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (@email, @firstname)

END
```

Comment: Check this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9644/1/0 Your table, your proc, your exec = works

Comment: Do you have Any triggers on the table?

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Why you using email address as a PK?

Comment: @PeteCarter Nothing wrong with an email address as a primary key. It does uniquely identify something.

Comment: Correct, it does, but you are building a whole b-tree on a varchar(something big). This will also be included in NCIs. I much rather have an artificial PK

Comment: NO triggers! I solved the problem? Must have been something wierd goign on yesterday because I did not change any code.. ?! Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed! Must have been something wierd with the online based admin I used yesterday. I ran the code today from SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO and it worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help anyway!